# Linking volumes in OSX?

Tags: macos

We have a video department at my office that uses Macs with Final Cut Pro.  They currently have a FC SAN that provides shared storage across the various video editing computers.  At present, there are two volumes shared on the SAN.  We just added a new storage array to the SAN and want to consolidate the two existing volumes into a single, larger volume.

We have the new volume created, and we're in the process of copying data from the two old volumes to it.  The problem we have is that I'm told Final Cut uses the volume name as part of the path it uses when it catalogs source media.  So for instance, if I have a volume named "Volume 1" and on that volume I have a folder called media and in that folder there is a file called file.mpg, then the full path Final Cut keeps track of is "Volume 1\media\file.mpg".

If I copy all of the files to a new volume, then all of the paths will be broken.  We can repair paths, but we're dealing with a lot of data so it's not something we want to do if we can avoid it.

What I'd rather do is create links.  So essentially, say I have the two old volumes that are called Volume 1 and Volume 2.  After I copy the data to the new volume, Volume 3, I'll remove Volume 1 & Volume 2 from the system, and I'd like to create a link that makes it appear that those two volumes still exist, however in reality those volumes will simply be links to Volume 3.

So the short version of my question is how can I make a link that will translate "Volume 1\media\file.mpg" into "Volume 3\media\file.mpg" in a way that Final Cut won't care about?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to do such a Link.

In MacOS-X all volumes are mounted unter `/Volumes` so if the stored path is `/Volumes/Volume 1` and your new Volume is mounted as `/Volumes/Volume 2` then you can create a symlink in Terminal like `ln -s /Volumes/Volume\ 2 /Volumes/Volume\ 1`